# how to filter request both modelname and districtname in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel-5

working with laravel 5.6 and mysql. I have following table name as `vehicles`

```
id  name  categoryname  brandname    model     districtname
1   juy   car           toyota       121       coba
2   gty   van           nissan       caravan   natai
3   bgh   car           bmw          520d      zenso
4   hyu   van           ford         max       mizuri
5   nhj   car           toyota       121       nakaga
6   gtr   car           toyota       corolla   wassa
7   gtr   van           nissan       caravan   goa
```

I have following controller function to filter request modelname,

```
$vehicles = Vehicle::with('uploads')
                ->when(request('modelname'), function ($query, $request) {
                    return $query->where('modelname', request('modelname'));
                })
                ->orderBy('adtype','DESC')
```

but now I need filter as above request both modelname and districtname also, how can I configure it as above controller?

Answer (score 0):

Add another one `when()` method.

```
$vehicles = Vehicle::with('uploads')
    ->when(request('model'), function ($query) {
        $query->where('model', request('model'));
    })
    ->when(request('districtname'), function ($query) {
        $query->where('districtname', request('districtname'));
    })
    ->orderBy('adtype','DESC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: my link is this `<a href="{{ route('vehicles.modelindex') }}?modelname={{$dis->modelname}}/?districtname={{$dis->districtname}}"` but your comment is not work

Comment: Show your controller.

Comment: `<a href="{{ route('vehicles.modelindex') }}?model={{ $dis->model }}&districtname={{ $dis->districtname }}"`

Comment: Correct link. And you have column `model` in attached schema, but use `modelname`. Where is mistake?

Comment: Ok, try new link and query now.